# Sample application highlighting the new features of ASP.NET MVC v2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a good full sample application which highlights the new features of ASP.NET MVC v2 (as opposed to the initial release of ASP.NET MVC)?

Answer (score 1):

You mean apart from ScottGu's? There is a download link there.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [ClubStarterKit v3 Preview](http://clubstarterkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36375#ReleaseFiles)... we're using MVC 2 Beta. Of course, I'm a bit bias in recommending it :)